# Android FATAL EXCEPTION: main With UniMag SDK

Tags: android, sdk

My first Android app and I'm trying to integrate with UniMag SDK. I've included my logic below. Basically I'm trying to use the UniMag SDK but the sample logic they supply is really complicated for what I need to do. Ultimately I'm just looking to build a web view that my swiper will send card data to via JS. No idea what this error is telling me. Here's my log cat:

```
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.simpleswipe2/.simpleswipe2.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at com.idtechproducts.acom.uniMagURLHelper.getLastXMLVersion(uniMagURLHelper.java:22)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at com.idtechproducts.unimagsdk.UniMagConfigHelper.downloadXMLFile(UniMagConfigHelper.java:56)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at com.idtechproducts.unimagsdk.UniMagConfigHelper.loadingXMLFile(UniMagConfigHelper.java:234)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at com.idtechproducts.unimagsdk.UniMagConfigHelper.loadingXMLFile(UniMagConfigHelper.java:48)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at IDTech.MSR.uniMag.uniMagReader.loadingConfigurationXMLFile(uniMagReader.java:485)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at .simpleswipe2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
 02-28 21:30:09.740: E/AndroidRuntime(25624):   ... 11 more
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.simpleswipe2/.simpleswipe2.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at com.idtechproducts.acom.uniMagURLHelper.getLastXMLVersion(uniMagURLHelper.java:22)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at com.idtechproducts.unimagsdk.UniMagConfigHelper.downloadXMLFile(UniMagConfigHelper.java:56)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at com.idtechproducts.unimagsdk.UniMagConfigHelper.loadingXMLFile(UniMagConfigHelper.java:234)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at com.idtechproducts.unimagsdk.UniMagConfigHelper.loadingXMLFile(UniMagConfigHelper.java:48)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at IDTech.MSR.uniMag.uniMagReader.loadingConfigurationXMLFile(uniMagReader.java:485)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at .simpleswipe2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
 02-28 21:33:27.505: E/AndroidRuntime(26259):   ... 11 more
```

My Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package=".simpleswipe2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".simpleswipe2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:text="Swipe" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Lastly, My Java File

```
package com.xxxxxxxx.simpleswipe2;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import IDTech.MSR.XMLManager.StructConfigParameters;
import IDTech.MSR.uniMag.uniMagReader;
import IDTech.MSR.uniMag.uniMagReaderMsg;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements uniMagReaderMsg {

    private uniMagReader myUniMagReader = null;
    private Button btnSwipe;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(myUniMagReader == null) {
            myUniMagReader = new uniMagReader(this,this);
            myUniMagReader.setSaveLogEnable(false);
            myUniMagReader.setXMLFileNameWithPath(null);
            myUniMagReader.loadingConfigurationXMLFile(true);

            //myUniMagReader.setVerboseLoggingEnable(true);
            myUniMagReader.registerListen();
        }

        btnSwipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnSwipe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myUniMagReader.startSwipeCard();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    myUniMagReader.stopSwipeCard();
        myUniMagReader.unregisterListen();
        myUniMagReader.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUserGrant(int arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "getUserGrant -- " + arg1);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgAutoConfigProgress(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgAutoConfigProgress");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgCardData(byte arg0, byte[] arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgCardData");
        Log.d("UniMag", "Successful swipe!");

        String strData = new String(arg1);
        Log.d("UniMag", "SWIPE - " + strData);
        if(myUniMagReader.isSwipeCardRunning()) {
            myUniMagReader.stopSwipeCard();
        }

        // Match the data we want.
        String pattern = "%B(\\d+)\\^([^\\^]+)\\^(\\d{4})";
        Log.d("UniMag", pattern);
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(strData);
        String card = "";
        String name = "";
        String exp = "";
        String data = "";
        if(m.find()) {
            for(int a = 0; a < m.groupCount(); ++a) {
                Log.d("UniMag", a + " - "+m.group(a));
            }
            card = m.group(1);
            name = m.group(2);
            exp = m.group(3);
            data = "Data: " + name + " -- " + card + " -- " + exp;
            Log.d("UniMag", data);

            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = data;
            swipeHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

    }

    final Handler swipeHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String text = (String)msg.obj;
            TextView dataView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            dataView.setText(text);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgCommandResult(int arg0, byte[] arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgCommandResult");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgConnected() {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgConnected");
        Log.d("UniMag", "Card reader is connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgDisconnected() {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgDisconnected");
        if(myUniMagReader.isSwipeCardRunning()) {
            myUniMagReader.stopSwipeCard();
        }
        myUniMagReader.release();

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgFailureInfo(int arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag","onReceiveMsgFailureInfo -- " + arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgSDCardDFailed(String arg0) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgSDCardDFailed -- " + arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgTimeout(String arg0) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgTimeout -- " + arg0);
        Log.d("UniMag","Timed out!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgToConnect() {
        Log.d("UniMag","Swiper Powered Up");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgToSwipeCard() {
        Log.d("UniMag","onReceiveMsgToSwipeCard");      
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgAutoConfigCompleted(StructConfigParameters arg0) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgAutoConfigCompleted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgAutoConfigProgress(int arg0, double arg1,
            String arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgProcessingCardData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgToCalibrateReader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a network operation on your main UI thread. At this line -

```
 myUniMagReader.loadingConfigurationXMLFile(true);
```

NetworkOnMainThreadException exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

You can use AsyncTask to run this task on a different thread.

Comment: That was it. I was able to use AsyncTask to work it out. Thank you.